# Solve transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug Error

Tags: android, android-studio

### How do i resolve this `Error:Execution failed` for task `app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug` in android studio

com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
        java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/http/ConnectionClosedException.class

```
    Here is my **build.grader** file



    repositories {
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

        // testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0"
        compile project(':slider')
        compile project(':caldroid')
        compile files('libs/FlurryAnalytics-6.2.0.jar')
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
        //compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.5'
        compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
        compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3.+'
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'    
        compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'
        compile files('libs/android-viewbadger.jar')
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'

    }


    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: show your `build.gradle`

Answer (score 0):

Try `./gradlew clean` It helped me